# Integration method that i forgot.

Tags: calculus

Which method of integration could i use for this integrate.

Im a begginer in intregations and im trying to find a solution for this, but i dont really find anything yet. if could help me i would thank you so much :D

$x^2/e^x$ dx

Comment: Integration by parts can be used here.

Comment: And writing the integrand as $x^2 e^{-x}$ can be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use integration by parts, so
let $x^2=u$ and $e^{-x}dx=dv$ so we have $$\int x^2e^{-x}dx=-x^2e^{-x}+\int 2xe^{-x}dx.$$ Now
 let  $2x=u$ and $e^{-x}dx=dv$ so we have  $$\int 2xe^{-x}dx=-2xe^{-x}+\int 2e^{-x}dx= -2xe^{-x}-2e^{-x}.$$ So we have that $$\int x^2e^{-x}dx=-(x^2+2x+2)e^{-x}+C$$